# How to not let my stack overflow?

Tags: c++

I expect to output:

`acej`

which works fine with this algorithm but there is a problem with outputting the result and this problem causes stack to overflow.

How do I fix it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<char> charAt(std::vector<char> str)
{
    std::vector<char> result;
    result.resize(str.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < str.size(); j++)
            {
                if (result[j] == '\0')
                {
                    result[j] = str[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, std::vector<char> vector)
{
    stream << "Vector: " << vector << std::endl;
    return stream;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<char> foo = { 'a', 'b','c','d','e','f','j' };
    std::vector<char> bar = charAt(foo);
    std::cout << bar << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: can you provide as well a minimal *working* example of how you're instanciating and calling this?

Comment: `stream << "Vector: " << vector << std::endl;` What did you expect this to do?

Comment: I don't think you have a stack overflow, but a plain bug. A vector of characters is not a string, so how come you expect it to contain `'\0'`?

Comment: @Lundin: It's an infinite recursion. Definitely stack overflow. Though you're right also, that's a bug. The loop iterates over `j` but then looks `j` up in the wrong container.

Comment: Oh, I didn't even read the code inside the overloaded operator :)

Comment: How about the algorithm itself? Any improvements?

Comment: oh, same, I missed the main part :-s

Comment: by the way, I would avoid using a class name `vector` as the name for a parameter (or a variable). your code just get less readable, and possibly, as it evolves and get more complicated, not compilable.

Comment: @Lundin:  He resizes the vector `result` to `str.size()`.  That will give you a vector full of `\0` characters to start with.  (I'd prefer to call the parameter `vec`, but I can see why the OP may think of it as a string (not a std::string of course).

Comment: Is there a reason for not declaring `charAt` with a reference parameter: `charAt(std:vector<char>& str)`? This would avoid a copy.

Answer (score 3):

Lets take a closer look at your output operator:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, std::vector<char> vector)
{
    stream << "Vector: " << vector << std::endl;
    return stream;
}
```

It's called when you output a `std::vector<char>`. It will then output a `std::vector<char>` which causes a recursive call, and so on in infinity (or until you get a stack overflow).

What your output operator needs to to is *iterate* over the vector and output each element.

---

On an unrelated note, don't pass the vector by value to the function. Instead use a constant reference:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, std::vector<char> const& vector) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, your `operator<<` is not only useless (since it does nothing but wrap the same line of code that you have in `main` anyway), but it's also calling itself recursively, so you get a SO eventually:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, std::vector<char> vector)
{
    stream << "Vector: " << vector << std::endl;
                         \__________/
                                ^
                                |
                             recursion right here  
    return stream;
}
```

You probably want something like

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, std::vector<char> vector)
{
    stream << "Vector: " << std::endl;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < vector.size(); ++i)
        stream  << vector[i] << " ";
    stream  << std::endl;
    return stream;
}
```

Also your `charAt` could be improved:

```
std::vector<char> charAt(const std::vector<char> & str)
{
    std::vector<char> result;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            result.push_back(str[i]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: `size_t i` if you want to avoid 'signed/unsigned comparison' warnings.  Personally I'd avoid the whole issue with `for (auto c: vector) { stream << c << ' ' ; }`

Answer (score 0):

Did you intend to use `std::string` and used incorrect STL container instead.

```
#include <iostream>

std::string charAt(std::string str)
{
    std::string result;
    result.resize(str.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < str.size(); j++)
            {
                if (result[j] == '\0')
                {
                    result[j] = str[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    std::string foo = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'j' };
    std::string bar = charAt(foo);
    std::cout << bar << std::endl;
}
```

Output

```
acej
```